# Flask redirect is not working, no error, and db isn't updated

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

When submitting my form, the page is not redirected. There are no errors; some information is added to the url, and that's it. The database is not updated afterwards.

```
`from regist import app
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for
from regist.models import Applicant
from regist.forms import RegisterForm
from regist import db

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/redirected')
def redirected():
      return render_template('page.html')      

@app.route('/join', methods=['GET','POST'])
def join():
    form=RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
          applicant_to_create=Applicant(name=form.name.data,
                                        surname=form.surname.data,
                                        gender=form.gender.data,
                                        dateOfBirth=form.dateOfBirth.data,
                                        address=form.address.data,
                                        qualifications=form.qualifications.data,
                                        email=form.email.data,
                                        phoneNumber=form.phoneNumber.data)  
          db.session.add(applicant_to_create)
          db.session.commit()   
          return redirect(url_for('redirected'))                     
    return render_template('join.html',form=form)  `
```

The initial url is: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/join"

After adding some dummy data, it becomes: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/join?search=+%28ru%28rzshrhf&csrf_token=ImIwZWIwODcyNWQ4MWNkYjNjYWJkNjE5NTNkY2MwZWE5Yzk4MjNkOTci.YR4veQ.eyoXQWv4kRShFiZMEbPXoWzsbL0&name=dhss&surname=sdh&gender=M&dateOfBirth=sdthdh&address=dshtes&qualifications=dshdh&email=dhr&phoneNumber=dshd&submit=submit"
I intentionally set the date field to accept text.

here is the form html code:

```
 {%extends 'layout.html' %}
{%block head%}
<title>form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/formstyle.css') }}">
{%endblock%}

{%block body%}
<body> 
    
        <h2>Join Us</h2>
        <span id="requiredFieldMessage">fields marked (*) are required</span>
        <form method="POST">
        <!--{{ form.hidden_tag() }}-->  
        <table id="formTable">
            <tr><td class="labelCell">{{ form.name.label()}}</td>   <td class="labelCell">{{ form.surname.label()}}</td></tr>   
            <tr><td>{{ form.name(class="textbox") }}</td><td>{{ form.surname(class="textbox") }}</td></tr>  
            <tr><td class="labelCell">{{ form.gender.label()}}</td> <td class="labelCell">{{ form.dateOfBirth.label()}}</td></tr>   
            <tr><td>{{ form.gender() }}</td>    <td>{{ form.dateOfBirth(class="textbox", placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy") }}</td></tr> 
            <tr><td class="labelCell">{{ form.address.label()}}</td>    <td class="labelCell">{{ form.qualifications.label()}}</td></tr>    
            <tr><td>{{ form.address(class="textbox", rows="5", cols="40", placeholder="Enter four or five line address") }}</td>    <td>{{ form.qualifications(class="textbox", rows="5", cols="40", placeholder="enter at least one certificate") }}</td></tr> 
            <tr><td class="labelCell">{{ form.email.label()}}</td>  <td class="labelCell">{{ form.phoneNumber.label()}}</td></tr>   
            <tr><td>{{ form.email(class="textbox") }}</td>  <td>{{ form.phoneNumber(class="textbox") }}</td></tr>   
            <tr colspan="2"><td><br>{{ form.submit(id="submitButton") }}<br></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: please show your html template code

Comment: It seems that your form does not have the right target and that it's not a post action. As said by gittert, the error is in html not in your python code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Flask-WTF.
Look at what the doc says about validate_on_submit:

> Note that you don’t have to pass request.form to Flask-WTF; it will
> load automatically. And the convenient validate_on_submit will check
> if it is a **POST request** and if it is valid.

[Source](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/quickstart/)

(emphasis is mine)

Your form should be submitted as **POST**, not GET. GET forms are rare (mostly search forms because the keywords are propagated in the URL, thus the queries can be shared or bookmarked)

What seems to happen here is that the condition `if form.validate_on_submit():` is **not true**. Once you've fixed your form to use POST, you should display an error message to the user if that condition fails, and ask them to correct their input then, rather than do a **silent redirect**. It is very irritating to have forms that don't perform **validation** like they should, and don't communicate clear feedback when errors occur...

All you need to do is add an else clause to your if and display the error messages that should already be available from Flask WTF. When you build a form, test it and make sure it does not accept garbage.

Comment: I had set post method for my form in the html. I just edited the original question with that. Unless I don't understand what you mean by 'submitted as post'

Comment: I suggest that you add a **target** to your form, to explicit state where the data should be submitted to. Something like `<form method="POST" target="{{ url_for('join') }}">` should be sufficient Right now, I don't know where it goes but probably not where you think it should.